# driver.FindElement(By.XPath issue

Tags: c#, xpath

Below code is not working. The click event not happening. Button identify correctly. What is the issue?

```
   IWebElement searchButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//button[@class='es-button'])[1]"));
    searchButton.Click();
```

Button HTML code is

```
<button type="button" class="es-button" onclick="formSubmit();"><span>Search</span></button>
```

I am trying to scrape webpage by using a console application